# Making RUBY actually open a file in Windows, not inside ruby

Tags: ruby, file, docx

I want Ruby to open a file (in particular a .docx file), but not open it in Ruby, but ACTUALLY open it, like if I doubled clicked the file in the explorer. I've searched and read but can't find the answer to this. Can this be done?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What you really want to do is start a process from Ruby (MS Word) and have that process open the file.  Try searching for how to launch a subprocess from Ruby.

Comment: just use the shell: `start myfile.docx`.

Comment: I searched how to launch a subprocess, but found nothing helpful. Regarding the shell, I know I could do it that way, but I'm really looking for Ruby to do it for me, that's what coding is about, isn't it? =)

Comment: You can use the shell call from ruby, e.g. with `system("start myfile.docx")`

Answer (score 0):

Ok the way for doing it was using `system("start myfile.txt")`.

However, this way does not support file names with spaces `(i.e. "my file.txt")`, so first I had to use the shell to find out what name my file had using `dir /X`, for this example it would be `MYFILE~1.TXT`, so I could tell Ruby to open the file with this name using the above mentioned method.